# How to add a custom list of stock tickers to an existing list of S&P 500 tickers scraped from wikipedia

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I'm a beginner with Python, but with the help of online tutorials and forums like this I was able to write the below code that pulls in the last month of pricing data for all names/tickers in the S&P 500 and saves them to separate csv files.

I would now like to enhance this code to continue to pull in the pricing data for the S&P 500 tickers, but also add my own custom list of tickers to the S&P 500 tickers and pull in pricing data for all tickers in the S&P 500 and my custom list too. This custom list is companies of interest that are not currently in the S&P 500, like SHOP, RIVN, DDOG, etc. and could change over time, but not frequently.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

S_AND_P_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'


def get_ticker_data(tickers: list):
    '''
    Obtain the price data for all tickers specified. Creates a csv file of price data for each
    ticker in the data folder.

    Parameters
    ----------
    tickers : list
        A list of the tickers to download the data for
    '''

    data = yf.download(
        tickers = tickers,
        period = '1mo',
        interval = '1d',
        #start = "2023-02-24", #20 days of data
        #end = "2023-03-23", #previous close
        group_by = 'ticker',
        threads = True,
    )
    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            df = data.loc[:, ticker.upper()].dropna()
            df.to_csv(f'data/{ticker}.csv', index = True)
        except:
            print(f'Ticker {ticker} failed to download.')

    return

def get_s_and_p_tickers() -> list:
    '''
    Get a list of all tickers currently in the S&P 500 index.
    '''
    return pd.read_html(S_AND_P_URL)[0]['Symbol'].tolist()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Check if a directory exists called 'data', if not, create it
    if not os.path.isdir('data'):
        os.mkdir('data')

    # Download one csv file per ticker and place it in the data directory
    get_ticker_data(get_s_and_p_tickers())
```

I tried adding a .append or .extend line below the "def get_s_and_p_tickers()" block, but to no success.

I would like to pull the list of tickers for the S&P 500 from wikipidia and then from my custom list and continue to download one csv file per ticker and place them in the data directory I have. So keeping the same process that already works, but just adding in a second source/list of ticker data to download a csv file for.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're not showing us what you tried, so we can't tell you what was wrong with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

the approach you describe should work . try replacing the last line of the code

```
get_ticker_data(get_s_and_p_tickers())
```

with

```
ticker_list = get_s_and_p_tickers()
ticker_list += [ ... my own list ..] 
get_ticker_data(ticker_list)
```

Comment: this works, thanks!

Comment: OK great glad to be of some help - can you pls mark the answer as correct? - thanks!